# Reading Data From FTP Server in Hadoop/Cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, ftp, stream, cascading

I want to read data from FTP Server.I am providing path of the file which resides on FTP server in the format ftp://Username:Password@host/path.
When I use map reduce program to read data from file  it works fine. I want to read data from same file through Cascading framework. I am using Hfs tap of cascading framework to read data. It throws following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPInputStream.close(FTPInputStream.java:98)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.close(LineReader.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.close(LineRecordReader.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

Below is the code of cascading framework from where I am reading the files:

```
public class FTPWithHadoopDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tap source = new Hfs(new TextLine(new Fields("line")), "ftp://user:pwd@xx.xx.xx.xx//input1");
        Tap sink = new Hfs(new TextLine(new Fields("line1")), "OP\\op", SinkMode.REPLACE);
        Pipe pipe = new Pipe("First");
        pipe = new Each(pipe, new RegexSplitGenerator("\\s+"));
        pipe = new GroupBy(pipe);
        Pipe tailpipe = new Every(pipe, new Count());
        FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef().addSource(pipe, source).addTailSink(tailpipe, sink);
        new HadoopFlowConnector().connect(flowDef).complete();
    }
}
```

I tried to look in Hadoop Source code for the same exception. I found that in the MapTask class there is one method runOldMapper which deals with stream. And in the same method there is finally block where stream gets closed **(in.close())**. When I remove that line from finally block it works fine. Below is the code:

```
private <INKEY, INVALUE, OUTKEY, OUTVALUE> void runOldMapper(final JobConf job, final TaskSplitIndex splitIndex,
            final TaskUmbilicalProtocol umbilical, TaskReporter reporter)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        InputSplit inputSplit = getSplitDetails(new Path(splitIndex.getSplitLocation()), splitIndex.getStartOffset());

        updateJobWithSplit(job, inputSplit);
        reporter.setInputSplit(inputSplit);

        RecordReader<INKEY, INVALUE> in = isSkipping()
                ? new SkippingRecordReader<INKEY, INVALUE>(inputSplit, umbilical, reporter)
                : new TrackedRecordReader<INKEY, INVALUE>(inputSplit, job, reporter);
        job.setBoolean("mapred.skip.on", isSkipping());

        int numReduceTasks = conf.getNumReduceTasks();
        LOG.info("numReduceTasks: " + numReduceTasks);
        MapOutputCollector collector = null;
        if (numReduceTasks > 0) {
            collector = new MapOutputBuffer(umbilical, job, reporter);
        } else {
            collector = new DirectMapOutputCollector(umbilical, job, reporter);
        }
        MapRunnable<INKEY, INVALUE, OUTKEY, OUTVALUE> runner = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(job.getMapRunnerClass(),
                job);

        try {
            runner.run(in, new OldOutputCollector(collector, conf), reporter);
            collector.flush();
        } finally {
            // close
            in.close(); // close input
            collector.close();
        }
    }
```

please assist me in solving this problem.

Thanks,
Arshadali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some efforts I found out that hadoop uses `org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem` Class for FTP.
This class doesn't supports seek, i.e. Seek to the given offset from the start of the file. Data is read in one block and then file system seeks to next block to read. Default block size is 4KB for `FTPFileSystem`. As seek is not supported it can only read data less than or equal to 4KB.